# Excel Macro Global Sub Adjustment

Tags: excel, vba, global, add-in

I am trying to create an add-in that will print format automatically (print area and some settings) when the users in my company open a file where the workbook name contains the string "en-us". The macro itself runs fine if I insert as a sub in a sample report. Code as follows:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
     If Wb.Name Like "*en-us*" Then
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim LastCol As Long
     Dim myRng   As Range
     Dim ws      As Worksheet

     For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         With ws
             LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
             LastCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(6, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(8, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(10, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(11, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(12, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(13, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(14, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(15, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(16, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(17, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(18, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(19, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(20, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(21, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(22, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(23, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, _
     .Cells(24, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Cells(25, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
             Set myRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
             .PageSetup.PrintArea = myRng.Address(external:=True)
         End With
     Next ws

     Sheets.Select
     Application.PrintCommunication = False
     With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
         .LeftHeader = ""
         .CenterHeader = ""
         .RightHeader = ""
         .LeftFooter = ""
         .CenterFooter = ""
         .RightFooter = ""
         .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
         .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
         .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
         .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
         .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
         .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
         .PrintHeadings = False
         .PrintGridlines = False
         .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
         .PrintQuality = 600
         .CenterHorizontally = False
         .CenterVertically = False
         .Orientation = xlLandscape
         .Draft = False
         .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
         .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
         .Order = xlDownThenOver
         .BlackAndWhite = False
         .Zoom = False
         .FitToPagesWide = 1
         .FitToPagesTall = 0
         .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
         .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
         .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
         .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
         .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
         .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
         .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
         .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
         .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
         .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
         .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
         .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
     End With
     Application.PrintCommunication = True
     Sheets(1).Select
     Else: MsgBox ("Not an Proph+IT Model")
     End If 

 End Sub
```

However, this will of course not run as an add in so I used the following article to create what I believe is call an application event (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx). The process the article explains works great with sample code but when I try it with the full code above it no longer works.

I am aware that when using application events references such as ThisWorkbook and Sheet no long works because they will just refer to the add-in instead of the active workbook but I do not know how to port the code.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could modify the code and/or explain to me what needs to change and why.

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Apologies for the beginning and end of the code being outside the blockqoute, the editor is being difficult.

Comment: Does it error or just not run when you test it on a Workbook with "en-us" in the name?

Comment: Use the `Wb` parameter that the event passes...